# pythonic way to filter a dictionary of arrays

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
d = { 'a':['a','b','c','d'], 
      'b':['a','b','c','d'], 
      'c':['a','b','c','d'], 
      'd':['a','b','c','d'], }
```

I would like to reduce this dictionary into a new one that contains 2 keys randomly selected from the full set of keys, and also only contains values that correspond to those random keys.

Here is the code I wrote that works, but I feel like there is probably a more pythonic way to do it, any suggestions?

```
import random

d = { 'a':['a','b','c','d'],
      'b':['a','b','c','d'], 
      'c':['a','b','c','d'], 
      'd':['a','b','c','d'], }


new_d = {}
r = d.keys()
random.shuffle(r)
r = r[:2]
r_dict = dict( (k,True) for k in r)
for k in r_dict:
    a = tuple(d[k])
    new_a = []
    for item in a:
        if item in r_dict:
            new_a.append(item)
    new_d[k] = new_a
```

"new_d" has filtered dictionary, for example:

```
{'a': ['a', 'b'], 'b': ['a', 'b']}
```

If 'a' and 'b' are the two random keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on FM's, with the underused [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) type:

```
>>> ks = set(random.sample(d, 2))
>>> dict((k, list(ks & set(d[k]))) for k in ks)
{'a': ['a', 'c'], 'c': ['a', 'c']}
```

Comment: +1: This is much, much faster than @FM's solution, and a bit faster than mine (@FM: 16.5 ms; @twneale: 48 ns; @JoshAdel: 77 ns).

Comment: thanks, this is my introduction to the set type it looks incredibly useful

Answer (score 1):

```
ks = set(random.sample(d.keys(), 2))
nd = dict( (k, list(v for v in d[k] if v in ks)) for k in ks )
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
import random
rk = random.sample(d.keys(),2)
new_d = {}
for k in rk:
    new_d[k] = list(set(d[k]).intersection(rk))
```